# My HTML webpage content is wider than screen on mobile device and some PCs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow

I have tried most of the suggestions I could find online, but I couldn't get anything to work.

My webpage content appears wider than screen size on mobile devices and some PCs

URL: https://www.ahhospitality.com

```
   html, body,{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
```

I have tried playing around with my CSS but still couldn't fix it.

Any help?

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself_) and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: Please provide a minimal and reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Well, the website isn't responsive and that's why it doesn't fit into the mobile screen. The code snippet you have provided is not enough to help you.

Comment: Please check your site on this link: https://ready.mobi/

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the website is actually displayed correctly but the user can scroll into a void to the left or right, try adding overflow-y: hidden; in CSS like this:

```css
body {
    overflow-z: hidden;
}
```

This may not be the perfect static solution but it works just fine. The overflow is then 
probably caused by another element overflowing the edge of the body.

Comment: I have tried that, and I have also added overflow: hidden; I have also tested with overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden. When viewed from a mobile device, the page content fits to the display, but the site's wallpaper and header extends wider in the display hence making it horizontally scroll